# Cómo ignorar atributo heredado en Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, herencia

Estoy heredando de la clase `AbstractUser` de Django, pero quiero ignorar un campo que viene en la herencia.

Por ahora lo más cercano que he logrado es sobrescribir los atributos que no necesito y guardarlos como `null`, pero me interesa evitar que esos campos heredados no se repliquen en la base de datos.

¿Habrá alguna forma de darle instrucciones a Django en el constructor de la clase para evitar que herede ciertos atributos?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Existe una opción la cual es [crear tu modelo personalizado](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#s-specifying-a-custom-user-model) de Usuario el cual debe cumplir algunos detalles claves de implementación que requiere Django,
pero bueno respodiendo a la pregunta **¿Habrá alguna forma de darle instrucciones a Django en el constructor de la clase para evitar que herede ciertos atributos?**

Sí, si hay una forma y es mediante el uso de los [descriptores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) te muestro un ejemplo de que tendrias que hacer para que eso fuese posible

```
class NoHeredar(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        raise AttributeError("No heredar atributo")

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        raise AttributeError("No heredar atributo")

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    last_name = NoHeredar()
```

De esta manera el atributo last_name no se heredaria